# Understanding the rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm struggling in my discrete mathematics class and need some clarification on a topic.

Recently we learned the truth table for P -> Q.

```
P   Q  (P → Q)
T   T   T
T   F   F
F   F   T
F   T   T
```

After that we learned about rules of inference - these are used to prove an argument to be true or false. However, I don't truly understand why these are necessary.

For example, one of the rules in Modus Ponens, which states this:

```
assume P → Q is true.
if p is true,
then Q is true as well.
```

When would that rule of inference ever be necessary in a real world application? Why would we need to assume a hypothesis such as P → Q to be true? What is the point of these "rules of inference" in a real world setting, or perhaps does anyone have a real world example where it's useful? (I'd like to know why these laws have a use so an example would be greatly appreciated. Something besides P= I ate my dog. and Q = there is a blizzard outside. I think my textbook is trying to confuse me with its examples...)

I apologize if this seems like an ignorant question - it's because I am ignorant and am seeking knowledge so I can dig myself out of this hole of confusion.

EDIT: I should probably add that my textbook uses weird example like p=the moon is made of cheese - assume it to be true. So I'm wondering how these rules are actually applicable when we are talking about things that are actually used in the real world - not moons made of cheese. I am a software engineering student, so I'm sure there's a use for this in coding and I just don't know what it is yet.

Comment: You probably use modus ponens unconsciously every day of your life. Why don’t you step blindly into a busy street? Because you know that **if** you do so, **then** you are quite likely to get hurt. That is an if-then fact that is part of your basic understanding of the world around you. And it is modus ponens that lets you conclude from it that stepping into that street would be a bad idea.

Comment: So does Modus Ponens prove cause and effect in if then statements? the if causes the then?

Comment: The if-then statements that we use in everyday life generally involve cause and effect or at least a strong correlation; in formal logic that need not be the case, which is one reason that your text uses such bizarre examples. The formal logical notions are similar to the everyday notions but not identical.

Comment: Oh interesting. Why should formal logic not use cause and affect? what's the benefit?

Comment: Because we want the truth value of a proposition to depend only on the truth values of its component parts and not on any extraneous connections. Besides, cause and effect is a surprisingly elusive notion when you actually start looking at it closely.

Comment: So what about for conditional propositions? is there a computer science application where using Modus Ponens (or any other rule of inference) is useful? I just don't see the benefit of proving the whole statement true if you aren't trying to create a connection between the hypothesis and conclusion

Comment: The conditional $p\to q$ itself creates a connection between $p$ and $q$ within the context in which that proposition is being used. For example, we do not need to know what $p$ and $q$ are, or whether there is any ‘real’ connection between them, to recognize that an argument by modus ponens — $p\to q$, and $p$ is true, so $q$ is true — is logically valid **no matter what** $p$ and $q$ are. It’s the form of the argument that determines whether it’s valid, not the content. As for computer science applications, the if-then statements in programming languages operate on the basis of mod. pon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real-world example to consider: "If it is raining, then it is cloudy."

This does *not* mean that rain *causes* cloudiness. It means only that, at the moment, it is *not* the case that it is raining and not cloudy. It permits all other combinations of truth values:

- It can be raining and cloudy
- It can be cloudy and not raining
- It can be not raining and not cloudy

Hence the entries in the truth table.

---

The use of bizarre falsehoods is often used in logic textbooks to demonstrate the principle of vacuous truth. In general, it states that for any propositions $A$ and $B$, we have the tautology:

$$A \implies (\neg A \implies B)$$

In words, all things follow from a falsehood. Sort of. If $A$ is true, then the implication $\neg A \implies B$ is also true (vacuously so). Fortunately, we cannot infer anything about the truth value of $B$ from this implication since the antecedent ($\neg A$) is assumed to be false.

To use a popular, bizarre example: "If pigs could fly then $X$."

Since pigs cannot fly, this implication will be true no matter what proposition we may substitute for $X$, be it true OR false. Of course, we cannot infer anything about the truth value of $X$ without more information.

Comment: This explanation motivates the truth table for material implication, but I don't see how it answers the OP's question on when *rules of inference*, perhaps involving implication as a connective, are used in the real world. An implicative statement is not the same as an argument involving modus ponens.

Comment: @lemontree Not sure what you are getting at. What could be more "real world" than the weather? And can you give an example of an  "implicative statement that is not the same as an argument involving modus ponens?" You must know that "A implies B" is not the same a "A causes B."

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example where you use Modus Ponens.

You know that every differentiable function at $ x=a$ is continuous at $ x =a$.

So, if $ g$ is special function differentiable at $ x=a$, you are Sure that $ g $ is continuous at $ x= a$.

Every man is mortal.

You are a man.

So, be sure, you are mortal.

My remark:
In mathematics, an implication never begins by a False statement.

Comment: I may complete by saying that every element of the empty set is the pope (for the case $F\implies \text{whatever}$), if that's not out of topic.

Comment: To be fair, the statements would also involve $\forall$ quantifiers combined with implications in a formal statement.  So applying them would involve first a ${\forall}E$ (universal quantifier elimination) and then a ${\rightarrow}E$ (conditional elimination, also known as modus ponens).